# Get multiple values from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table customers

```
| id | firstname | 
| 1  | paul      |
| 2  | steve     |
| 3  | chris     |
```

second table called list_customer

```
| id | id_customer | id_list |
| 1  |     1       |    1    |
| 2  |     1       |    2    |
| 3  |     2       |    1    |
```

Each  customer can be in x number of lists

third table called list

```
| id_list | color |
|    1    | #fff  |
|    2    | #000  |
|    3    | #ccc  |
```

With mysql query I want to get firstname and list colors. 
Customers can be in multiple numbers of lists.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php... everything you need to know

Comment: thank you I will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.firstname, group_concat(l.color) as colors
from customers c
inner join list_customer lc on lc.id_customer = c.id
inner join list l on l.id_list = lc.id_list
group by c.firstname
```

Comment: Yes this one works for me thank you. Is there a way to get colors as array ?

Comment: If you mean in PHP, then no. That is not my area. Try another question if you can't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME, 
       l.COLOR AS ListColors 
FROM   CUSTOMERS c, 
       LIST_CUSTOMER lc, 
       LIST l 
WHERE  lc.ID_CUSTOMER = c.ID 
       AND l.ID_LIST = lc.ID_LIST 
GROUP  BY c.FIRSTNAME
```